# PHP, MYSQL get 1st and second row only of result array

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query that result like this.

```
SELECT check.c_id, check.voucher, check.payee, check.c_date, transact.atc_code, transact.value
    FROM `check`
    LEFT JOIN `transact`
    ON check.c_id = transact.t_id
    WHERE t_id='1' AND (atc_code LIKE '%72%' OR atc_code LIKE '%35%')
    ORDER BY check.c_id
```

```
"c_id"   "voucher"      "payee"                     "c_date"        "atc_code"      "value"
"1"      "PDMK162953"   "TOYOTA GLOBAL CITY, INC."  "04/11/2016"    "MK-GF-7202"    "10338.44"
"1"      "PDMK162953"   "TOYOTA GLOBAL CITY, INC."  "04/11/2016"    "MK-GF-3505"    "206.77"
```

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $c_id = $row['c_id'];
    $voucher = $row['voucher'];
    $payee = $row['payee'];
    $c_date = strtotime($row['c_date']);
    $atc_code = $row['atc_code'];
    $income = $row['value'];
    $tax = $row['value'];
}
```

How will i able to echo out the column 'value' to table first cell 10338.44 and 206.77 in the other cell of the table in html

Answer (score 2):

Just mention limit in your query.

```
SELECT check.c_id, check.voucher, check.payee, check.c_date, transact.atc_code, transact.value
FROM `check`
LEFT JOIN `transact`
ON check.c_id = transact.t_id
WHERE t_id='1' AND (atc_code LIKE '%72%' OR atc_code LIKE '%35%')
ORDER BY check.c_id
LIMIT 2    // Add this
```

Showing records in one row and two columns:

```
 <table border="1">
   <tr>
     <th>Tax 1</th>
     <th>Tax 2</th>
     <?php  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
     <td>
       <?php  echo $row['value']; ?>
     </td>
     <?php } ?>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: when im calling the variable $value it returns both 206.77 value. Instead i need to echo out 10338.44 for <td> 1 </td> and 206.77 for <td> 2 </td>

Comment: Are there duplicate entries for 206.77? Or that may be the cause of LEFT JOIN. You could try INNER JOIN, but I'm not sure what data you have in your two tables.

Comment: the query is always result into two records only. I just want to separate the result from column values into two columns. tnx

Comment: You mean you want to show these in two different td's? Like <td>206.77</td> and <td>10338.44</td> This way?

Comment: Also, do you want just one row and two columns? If so, you have to run your loop after the <tr> .